# Can we know if a window has been closed by the user or code on WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a window control that I show on my app. Sometimes, the window is closed by the user (clicking on the 'X' button) and sometimes automatically by code.

I'm listening to the Closed event (also tried with Closing) and would like to know in which case I am (user or code). Is this possible?

(I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175991/how-can-you-determine-whether-a-form-has-been-closed-by-the-user-or-by-your-code) question but it really doesn't have a satisfactory answer)

EDIT:

I'm looking for a simple solution, or some way of knowing where the event originated. I know I can implement this functionality myself as Sandeep Bansal suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:
Define a new type

```
 public class CodeClosingEventArgs : EventArgs
 { 
  // Fill any custom data you want
 }
```

And then call `OnClosed(new CodeClosingEventArgs());` explicit in your code and check for the Event Type,  if its a "normal" event arg, its the user by clicking the 'X'.

Option 2:

use a custom method which closes your form.

```
 public void MyClosingFormMethod()
 {
    base.OnClosed(null); 
 }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? There's no CloseReason anywhere on a window control.

Comment: CloseReason is an Enum Type which must be provided with the FormClosedEventArgs. You basically call this event manually.

Comment: Ah snap, thats true. But what you could do is OnClosed(null); and do a null-check on the Event Arg. If its null => programatically closed. If its not null, its a user input.

Comment: See my edit. Its probably even better to use a custom EventArgs Type.

Comment: Yeah, but anyways, this way I have to work it before raising the event. That's exactly what I wanted to avoid. I want to know where the event originated without having to "tell" it myself. Thanks anyway, +1 :)

Comment: Would implementing a custom Close Method help? private void ProgrammaticallyClose() {  base.OnClosed(null) }. That way you can clearly determine who's was calling from where.

Comment: I think that would be a good compromise. If you edit the answer I'll tick it, thanks

Comment: For some reason, when i call base.OnClosed(null); nothing happens for me, i.e. window doesn't close.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a boolean value and then set it if the certain activity occurs?

```
bool closedByUser = false;
```

and then where the code is meant to close the form just add `closedByUser = false;` and `closedByUser = true;` if the action is user derived.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I'm looking for a solution that does not require me to set a variable. It could get cumbersome if there are many cases. Anyways, +1 ;)