# How do I know if a form has been closed by the user or code on Winforms?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, timer

I am displaying a form and after 30 seconds the form has to be closed automatically.
For closing the form, I am calling this.Close() from Timers.Timer control which will close the form after 30 seconds.

```
    private void timerClose_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                this.Close();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

But if the user wishes to close the form by clicking X button, then I should be able to differentiate whether the form is closed by user or timer.
I do have FormClosed event to do some stuff when closing but here I need to know whether the form is closed by user or timer.

```
    private void DISPLAY_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some stuff
        timerClose.Stop();
    }
```

how do I know the form has been closed by User or Timer in FormClosed Event?

The following link doesn't help

[Can we know if a window has been closed by the user or code on WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210807/can-we-know-if-a-window-has-been-closed-by-the-user-or-code-on-wpf)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no point in using a System.Timers.Timer, use the Timer from the toolbox.  And all you need is a simple *bool* field in your class, set it to *true* in your Tick event handler.  Now you know.

Comment: I know that. but my need is different.

Comment: No it is not, to accomplish what you need just use a bool

Comment: Added an example of how to use a bool for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make a `bool` (I call it closed by user) and change it accordingly when the timer closes your form. In this case if the timer closes it, it is no longer "closed by the user" so I set it to `false`. Then in your closing event just check the bool.

**Example:**

```
//As long as its not closed by the system, its closed by the user
private bool closedByUser = true;

private void timerClose_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
        {
            //closed by system
            closedByUser = false;
            this.Close();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

private void DISPLAY_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if(closedByUser)
        timerClose.Stop();
        //Closed by user
    else
        timerClose.Stop();
        //Not closed by user
}
```