# Check if opened window has been closed

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

I have a main window, which is the application start up window.
In that window, there is a `Repeater` control binded to a `SQL Database`, and a button to open a new window.

The new window has a method that inserts data into the `SQL Database` that the first windows' `Repeater` control reads from.

The repeater has a `RepeaterRefresh()` method that forces it to rebind to the `SQL Database`, revealing anything added.

How would I be able to bind the `Close()` event of the second window to the `RepeaterRefresh()` method, so the data is automatically shown on the repeater.

I have read [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c521ac47-7326-483a-be60-42de0e355711/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210807/can-we-know-if-a-window-has-been-closed-by-the-user-or-code-on-wpf) [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175991/how-can-you-determine-whether-a-form-has-been-closed-by-the-user-or-by-your-code), but I still feel that my question doesn't relate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you tell if a WPF Window is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381973/how-do-you-tell-if-a-wpf-window-is-closed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not simply add a handler to the [Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.100)) or [Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed(v=vs.100)) event:

```
private void ShowChildWindow()
{
    Window childWindow = new ChildWindow();
    childWindow.Closed += ChildWindowClosed;
    childWindow.Show();
}

private void ChildWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Window)sender).Closed -= ChildWindowClosed;
    RepeaterRefresh();
}
```

Comment: The ChildWindowClosed method will need this line: (sender as Window).Closed -= ChildWindowClosed;