# How do I reset a window on button click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application, I would like to reset a window on button click. But only a specific window, not my all application.

I have 3 windows: main, second and third.

Main opens second and second opens third.

When I close third with a button that executes `this.Close()`, I would like to restart second window too.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please, provide us sample of your code. How do you initialize this window?

Comment: It is a lot of code. I just open it through a button click in another window and execute a `win.Show()`

Comment: So, you can close this window and open new one. What the problem is?

Comment: @YuriDorokhov I've updated my question.

Comment: when you create a window just hook up to closing event, and then refresh the calling window inside that event.

Comment: see this q/a please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106657/check-if-opened-window-has-been-closed

Comment: @adminSoftDK I've done something similar. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If your project or code is based on MVVM, the Command should reference the specific Dependency object you want to manipulate in the Visual Tree as a parameter.

Comment: No, it's not MVVM based.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do with using MVVM framework like MVVM Light and use messaging between windows.

For Example:
Create specific message

```
public class RefreshWindowMessage
{
   public Guid Identity { get; set; }
}
```

Send message when you close third

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new RefreshWindowMessage("<some guid of window>"));
```

Register message in your main window

```
Messenger.Default.Register<RefreshWindowMessage>
( 
     this, 
     ( action ) => ReceiveMessage( action ) 
);
```

and restart second window in action.